# In Weaviate hybrid search, why does withOffset is not working as expected?

Tags: weaviate

We have tried using [Weaviate hybrid search](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/api/graphql/vector-search-parameters#hybrid) for our search platform and it provides better results as it can now catch both keywords matching and vector search. However, unlike `nearText` search - it seems that the `offset` parameter is not working though you are allowed to configure it, as can be seen below:

```
    HybridArgument hybridArg = weaviateClient.graphQL().arguments().hybridArgBuilder()
            .query(request.getQuery())
            .alpha(0.5f)
            .build();
    Get getBuilder = weaviateClient.graphQL().get()
            .withClassName(className)
            .withFields(...)
            .withLimit(25)
            .withOffset(25)
            .withHybrid(hybridArg);
```

From above configuration regardless of the configured `offset` - it will always return the **top 25 results** and will not get the next **26 - 50** items (even if `offset` was set to **25**)

Hence, is this an expected behavior for hybrid search and there is no way for me to get a somehow paginated or offset-based search results?

Comment: Well spotted. This is a bug and will be fixed in the next Weaviate release. https://github.com/weaviate/weaviate/pull/3083

Comment: Thanks @BobvanLuijt for the PR reference - btw I have filed a Github issue for it last week just in case I will not get answers in SO. Please see it here: https://github.com/weaviate/weaviate/issues/3076